# Pointer questions in c

Tags: c, pointers, declaration

Quick question about C programming. I haven't taken a course on it, but was reading online about pointers and the various notations used. Does the following line result in an array of 10 pointers to integers, or a pointer to an array of 10 ints?

```
int *x[10];
```

Also does the following result in a function that takes a double as input and returns a pointer to a character?

```
char (*f) (double a);
```

Thanks in advance!

Edit: Typed the first line of code incorrectly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A function that takes a double as input and returns a `char` pointer would look like this:

```
char * foo(double arg);
```

Where `arg` is your input double, `foo` is the name of the function, and `char *` is the return type, a char pointer.

```
char (*foo)(double arg);
```

Declares a function pointer to a function that takes a double (`arg`) and returns a `char`.

---

Your attempt at creating an array is missing a variable name.  And there are two different ways to do this...

```
int * array[10];
```

This declares an array with 10 indexes that holds `int *`, int pointers.

```
int (*array)[10];
```

This declares a pointer to an array of ints with size of 10.

Answer (score 2):

`int *x[10];` means that `x` is an array with 10 elements, each of which is a pointer to `int`.

`char (*f) (double a);` means that `f` is a pointer to a function that returns `char` and has one parameter of type `double`.

Comment: Thanks, I typed up the first line wrong but corrected it, so hopefully that's no longer an error.